# Passing floats between views

Tags: cocoa, view, floating-point, nsuserdefaults

I have been using NSUserDefaults for passing floats all around my apps. But they are starting to not work for me anymore. I just get NAN. Is there another way to do the same thing? I have been toying around with some singleton classes but all that does is crash my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was just taking the square root of a negative number. NSUserDefaults FTW!
I also got my singleton to work great. I actually ended up not using it because I found how to store and pull objects like NSMutableArray and NSMutableDictionary out of NSUserDefaults.